# Powershell Get-Item Object or Array

Tags: arrays, object, powershell

In a directory i do

```
Get-Item *.txt
```

When there is one .txt file inside the directory it returns a System.IO.FileSystemInfo

When there are more .txt files it returns a 
System.Array

What is the best way to handle this inconsistency? I.e. how do i find out if the function returned an object or an array. Or even better, is there a way that Get-Item always returns an array?

I want to pass the result into an other function. This function expects an array of System.IO.FileSystemInfo objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force an array to always return:

```
@(Get-Item *.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `ForEach-Object`

```powershell
Get-Item *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    # Do stuff
    $_   # this represents the "current" object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to insure the result will always be an array is to wrap the expression in @():

```
@(Get-Item *.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Alternately*, if you are holding the result in a variable for use later, just specify an [array]

```
[array]$list = Get-Item *.txt
```

This is useful if you want (eg) $list.count which only works with an array.  Otherwise you end up with code like:

```
if ( $result -eq $null) {
  $count = 0
} elseif ($list -isnot [array]) {
  $count = 1
} else {
  $count = $result.count
}
```